# How to workaround orElseThrow mock

Tags: java, mockito

I have a `ProductService` that through `ProductRepository` queries a database. In there I have an update method and a find method. The update method is `updateProductInDatabase(String id, Product updateInfo)`. The `updateProductInDatabase` calls a method `findProductInDatabaseById(String id)` which return Product or throws a ResourceNotFoundException.

My code:

```
public void updateProductInDatabase(String id, Product updateInfo) {
   Product product = findProductInDatabaseById(id);
   if (correctFormat(updateInfo.getVersion()) {
       product.setVersion(updateInfo.getVersion());
       repository.save(updateInfo);
       //restOfTheCode
   } else {
       // Throws invalid input exception
   }
}

private Products findProductInDatabaseById(String id) {
   Optional<Product> productOptional = 
        repository.getAllProducts().stream.findFirst(); // return a list, but I only need the first
   return productOptional.orElseThrow(...) // Throws resource not found exception
}
```

I want to write unit test for this code that expects the invalid input exception, but the test fails with

> unexpected exception: expected InvalidInputException, but found
> ResourceNotFoundException

This happens because productOptional is always an empty optional.

Can someone help in providing a workaround to mocking productOptional ?

Edit: adding my test

```
    @Test(expected = InvalidInputException.class)
public void testUpdateProductVersionInDatabaseWhenVersionIsIncorrectFormat()
        throws ApiException {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setVersion("error-version");
    when(repository.getAllProducts())
            .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new Product()));
    productService.updateProductInDatabase("product-id-1", product);
}
```

Comment: share a test please

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I just added the test

Comment: ok then, you throw a `ResourceNotFoundException`  but the `InvalidInputException` placed as expected, so what's wrong? Change expected value to `ResourceNotFoundException`

Comment: I don't want the `ResourceNotFoundException ` to be thrown, I want the service to throw `InvalidInputException` after checking the version format

Comment: Your code does not makes much sense. Especially the `findProductInDatabaseById`: void method which returns something and the ID is never concerned. So could you please provide the correct code? Further: `ResourceNotFoundException`-> is this a custom exception you declare as supplier in `orElseThrow` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
List<Product> products = new LinkedList<>();
products.add(new Product()); // add product

Mockito.when(repository.getAllProducts()).thenReturn(products);
```

Comment: Yes, I've done this when(repository.getAllProducts(any())).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new Product()));

Comment: The repository.getAllProducts you are calling does not take any parameter so you need to add another when(repository.getAllProducts()).thenReturn that does not have any parameter

Comment: My mistake, I copied that from a different test case that tests the other method getAllProducts(id) (which also doesn't work)

Comment: Just covering all the bases, your declaration for repository is annotated with @Mock? and that productService is using this mock repository.

Comment: Yes, but somehow the Optional product is empty

Comment: Have you injected the mock to the corresponding service or how do you get your mock inside the service class.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the state of the DB isn't sutable for the test since you expect some data meanwhie there are no products. Insert some product before the test.
If you really don't care of the data, then yes, it could be mocked:

```
class ProductServiceTestClass {
  @Mock
  ProductRepository repository;

  @InjectMocks
  ProductService productService;

    @Test(expected = InvalidInputException.class)
    public void testUpdateProductVersionInDatabaseWhenVersionIsIncorrectFormat()
            throws ApiException {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setVersion("error-version");
        when(repository.getAllProducts())
                .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new Product()));
        productService.updateProductInDatabase("product-id-1", product);
    }
}
```

Note that it won't work if `ProductRepository` injected by `@Autowired`. In this case the real Spring bean will be used instead. Change its injection to constructor or setter way.

Comment: My code is identical to the one you posted, but it is still throwing ResourceNotFoundException from the `findProductInDatabaseById` method

Comment: It is injected with the constructor, but it is still not working

Comment: do you see the injected mock while debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code so the validation method can be unit tested

Extract method `correctFormat(updateInfo.getVersion()` to a utility class like :
`VersionValidator.isCorrectFormat(String version)`

you will be able to unit test it :

```
@Test
public void should_return_false_on_incorrect_format_version()
        throws ApiException {
    String uncorrectFormat = "LTS.x.v15dssdf";
    boolean isCorrect = VersionValidator.isCorrectFormat(uncorrectFormat);
    assertThat(isCorrect).isFalse()
}
```

anyway, if you want to keep with an integration test, your method `repository.getAllProducts()` should at least return a product.

```
public void updateProductInDatabase(String id, Product updateInfo) {
   if (!correctFormat(updateInfo.getVersion()) {
       //throw
   }
   Product product = findProductInDatabaseById(id);
   product.setVersion(updateInfo.getVersion());
   repository.save(updateInfo);
   //restOfTheCode
   
}
```